# How I can convert haskell [char] to CString

Tags: c, haskell

My code in haskell have some error:
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Ptr CChar’
      Expected type: CString
        Actual type: [Char]

Source code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Foreign.C -- get the C types
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr,nullPtr)
import Foreign.C.String

foreign import ccall "stdio.h printf"
  myprintf :: CString -> IO CString

main = do
  myprintf "hello"
```

Comment: Why `"stdio.h printf"` instead of `"printf"`?

Comment: In some examples I saw this practice

Answer (score 7):

The literal `"hello"` is of type `String` (also known as `[Char]`), not of type `CString`, so you can't pass it to `myprintf`. The types don't match.

You can convert it to `CString` via the [`newCString` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.17/base-4.12.0.0/Foreign-C-String.html#v:newCString):

```
main = do
    str <- newCString "hello"
    myprintf str
```

Or in a more compact way:

```
main =
    myprintf =<< newCString "hello"
```

---

On a related note, I think your imported signature is incorrect. The function `printf` from `stdio` doesn't return a string, it returns an `int`.

Since you're just discarding the return value, it's no big deal (or is it? not sure how FFI would work here), but if you try to actually use it while assuming it's a `CString`, unpredictable bad things may happen.

Comment: `printf` in C is a variadic function, I'm not sure if we can import that so easily ignoring the variadic part of arguments. Maybe we can with `ccall`. Further, I believe that that `CString` has to be freed manually (?)

Comment: A shame `Cstring` is a type alias, so that you can't define an `IsString` instance for it.

Comment: @chepner you can create instances for aliases (after all, `String` itself has an instance), the problem is that converting `String` to `CString` is not a pure operation.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Ah, right. I was confusing that with the case where the aliased type already has an instance, in which case the alias isn't sufficient for creating a separate instance.